# Do maximal and maxiumum elements coincide for totally preordered sets?

Tags: order-theory

Let $A$ be some finite and countable set, and let $R$ be a **[total preorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Total_preorders)** (i.e., a preference relation) on $A$: that is, a binary relation on $A$ satisfying

1. **Transitivity**: for all $a,b,c\in A$, $aRb$ and $bRc$ imply $aRc$.
2. **Reflexivity**: for all $a\in A$, $aRa$.
3. **Completeness**: for all $a,b\in A$, $aRb$ or $bRa$.

Then, $(A,R)$ is a **totally preordered set**.

Let $P$ be a **[preorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preorder)** on $A$: that is, a binary relation on $A$ satisfying

1. **Transitivity**: for all $a,b,c\in A$, $aPb$ and $bPc$ imply $aPc$.
2. **Reflexivity**: for all $a\in A$, $aPa$.

Then, $(A,P)$ is a **preordered set**.

Consider $(A,P)$ and some $B\subseteq A$. Then, $m\in B$ is a **[maximal element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_and_minimal_elements)** of $B$ with respect to $P$ if:
\begin{equation}
(\forall b\in B)[(mPb)\Rightarrow(bPm)]
\end{equation}

Further, $\tilde{m}\in B$ is a **[maximum element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_element_and_least_element)** of $B$ with respect to $P$ if
\begin{equation}
(\forall b\in B)(bP\tilde{m})
\end{equation}

For partially ordered sets, *maximal* and *maximum* elements do not need to coincide. However, **do *maximal* and *maxiumum* elements coincide for totally preordered sets?**

Comment: Your definition of "maximum element" seems to be backwards. Also I would call what you call "asymmetry" "reflexivity". And did you mean $(A, P)$ is a preordered set, rather than $(A, Q)$? If you fix the definition then yes, they coincide in totally preordered sets. Clearly maximum implies maximal, and conversely, maximal implies maximum due to your axiom 3.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the two errors in my OP. I have now corrected them.

Comment: I would say your two definitions are now of "maximal element" and "minimum element", so you should change one of them. In your original post they were "minimal" and "minimum" (which I didn't realise at the time of writing my first comment - sorry!). Of course it's a bit of a triviality - it depends if you're thinking of the relation as $\le$ or $\ge$, but I think the former is more common. The two versions of the question are equivalent by duality.

Comment: Are my definitions of maximal and maximum fine now?

Comment: Yep, that looks good to me! Does my short explanation for why they are equivalent in my first comment make sense? It's a pretty straightforward fact to prove, I think, if you just sit down and try to prove each direction.

Comment: Yes, it’s a very intuitive statement to prove, because as soon as all elements become comparable, then any maximal element will be a maximum one.